# Convert short form month name to month number

Tags: php

```
$month_name = 'Feb';
$month_number = date("m", strtotime($month_name));
```

From above code, I get the output is 03 not 02. Why?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe it's because `strtotime()` doesn't realise it's a actual month from just that, if you add 1 in front of feb it seems to work for me.

Comment: u cant use this string in strtotime, check this: http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php .... or use 1 Feb

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's caused by current date and default value of date in `strtotime` function. Today we have 31 December so if you use strtotime, default value of date will be 31 Dec 2015, but if you change month to Feb the date will be 03 Mar 2015. Solution here is to add first day number at the begining e.g.

```
$month_name = '1 Feb';
$month_number = date("m", strtotime($month_name));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `date_parse()`:

```
$month_name = 'Feb';
$date = date_parse($month_name);
echo $date['month'];
```

Answer (score 1):

what about like this ... simple way ...

```
$mons = array("Jan" => 1, "Feb" => 2, "Mar" => 3, "Apr" => 4, "May" => 5, "Jun" => 6, "Jul" => 7, "Aug" => 8, "Sep" => 9, "Oct" => 10, "Nov" => 11, "Dec" => 12);    
$month_name = 'Feb';    
$month_number = $mons[$month_name];
```

Comment: nice and very simple...

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` will not work like that. You can check in PHP Manual. Here you can use `date_parse`.

```
$month = 'Feb';
$month = date_parse($month);
echo $month['month'];
```

This function will return you an array like:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 
    [month] => 2
    [day] => 
    [hour] => 
    [minute] => 
    [second] => 
    [fraction] => 
    [warning_count] => 1
    [warnings] => Array
        (
            [4] => The parsed date was invalid
        )

    [error_count] => 0
    [errors] => Array
        (
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
)
```

Now, you can get the month name or anything else.

Or, you still want to use `strtotime` function than you can try it as:

```
$month = '1 Feb';
$month = date("m",strtotime($month));
echo $month;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a full date as follows:

```
$month_name = 'Feb';
$month_number = date("m", strtotime("1-".$month_name."-2015"));
```